# Load connection strings programmatically

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord

Right now I have to specify connection strings for active record/nhibernate in my config file like so:

```
<activerecord>
    <config type="Navtrak.Business.Schemas.CommonSchemas.Models.NavtrakOperations.NavtrakOperationsDatabase`1, CommonSchemas">
      <add key="connection.connection_string" value="connstring1" />
      <add key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
      <add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect" />
      <add key="connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
      <add key="show_sql" value="true" />
      <add key="proxyfactory.factory_class" value="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle" />
    </config>
    <config type="Navtrak.Business.Schemas.CommonSchemas.Models.Users.UsersDatabase`1, CommonSchemas">
      <add key="connection.connection_string" value="connstring2" />
      <add key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
      <add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect" />
      <add key="connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
      <add key="show_sql" value="true" />
      <add key="proxyfactory.factory_class" value="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle" />
    </config>
  </activerecord>
```

Then I initialize active record:

```
if (!ActiveRecordStarter.IsInitialized)
                ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(typeof(SimpleModel).Assembly, ActiveRecordSectionHandler.Instance);
```

These connection strings must be database-driven so I need a way to programmatically set them. How can I do so? Keep in mind that I connect to multiple databases, in case that makes a difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `InPlaceConfigurationSource`. Some examples:

- http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/configref.html#InPlaceConfigurationSource
- http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2007/09/06/three-ways-to-configure-castle-activerecord.aspx
- http://geekswithblogs.net/hammett/articles/76809.aspx
- http://code.google.com/p/mausch/source/browse/trunk/LazyTests/FirebirdTests.cs?spec=svn359&r=334#22
- http://www.mail-archive.com/castle-project-users@googlegroups.com/msg04503.html